# react native select buttons and count

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to select buttons and then display how many I selected. Something like this:

[image]

I selected 4 buttons and I want the text to show "selected:4". Also if I unselect 2, I want the text to show "selected:2.

This is my code:

```
class RegionBT extends Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    onToggle: () => {},
  }

  state = {
    status: [{ toggle: false }],
    count: ''
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
     this.setState({
         count: this.state.count + 1
     });
    }

  handleDecrement = () => {
     this.setState({
       count: this.state.count - 1
     });
    }


  _onPress() {
    const newState = !this.state.toggle
    this.setState({ toggle: newState })
    this.props.onToggle(newState)
    {this.handleDecrement}
  }

  render() {
    const { count } = this.state
    const { toggle } = this.state
    const buttonBG = toggle ? '#6AAAC6' : 'white'
    const textColor = toggle ? 'gray' : 'gray'


    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={()=>this._onPress()}
      style={{width:'70%', height:'70%',backgroundColor:buttonBG, justifyContent:'center',
      borderColor:'#E0E0E0', borderWidth:1}}>
      <Text style={{color:textColor, textAlign:'center', fontSize:13}}>{this.props.text}</Text>
      <Text>{count}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

I think I did the code correctly but its not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What issue are you facing with this code?

Comment: Counting is not changing. i want the state to change.